# Java looping a method if it throws exception

Tags: java, loops, exception

I have a method that if the array[x][y] cell is not empty, throws an exception: CellNotEmptyException.
I need to run that method, and if it throws the exception, i need to re-run it, until it will find an empty cell, and for a max of 5 times.
If it doesnt find an empty cell within 5 times, it has to clean the array, and then re-run!!

Is there a way?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's called a `catch` statement

Comment: Got a good chuckle from Sotirios' answer: programmers are a very literal-minded bunch. Our point is that it is not clear *which part* of your problem you don't know how to do. It *is* possible - try coding it, see how far you get, and then if you have a *specific* question, come back and post it, with code.

Comment: Just Try your question by coding yourself when ever you get the Exception or stuck at a particular point Then after come along with stacktrace to StackOverflow Defenitely we will Help you @luca89pe Never discourage yourself and try to build the confidence through your own implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// loop forever until TheMethod() succeeds

while (true)
{
    try
    {
        TheMethod();
        break;
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

**This might be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) situation, though.** Iteratively calling a function until a cell is found doesn't sound like a great design to me. And throwing an exception is slow, so if this is a "normal" behavior of your program, consider some other mechanism than exceptions for finding an empty cell. Exceptions are for *exceptional* program conditions, not normal operation.

Comment: Thank you, this is the point!!!!
so is it better a boolean returning method, instead of throwing exception?

Comment: @luca89pe Probably. But without seeing the rest of your code and knowing the scenario I can't give you a definitive suggestion; there may be a better design.

Comment: The code is simply this:
`code`if(!this.grid.isEmptyCell(row, col)) throw new NotEmptyCellException
used in a function that generate random row and col, so, for being clear: finding a not empty cell, is not a really exceptional event, so i think i will use the return true - return false :)
Thank you!!!